# Assistance in proving a tautology using a series of logical equivalences.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am trying to prove, using a series of logical equivalence rules, that the following formula is a tautology:

$$[a∧(a→b)∧(b→c)]→c$$

Yet despite numerous successes on other tautologies and logical equivalences proofs, I find myself getting stuck on this rather obvious syllogism.

A quick and easy truth table reveals this formula to be true, so I know that I am making a mistake somewhere.

Please note, I am not formally studying Propositional or Predicate Logic. Rather, I am studying this topic in my own time for a bit of fun.

Comment: You can try exploting the equivalence between $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$; then De Morgan... Id you will find a disjunction with at least one disjunct of the form $p \lor \lnot p$ you are done, because a disjunction of clauses one of which is $T$ is a *tautology*.

Comment: How about trying an old strategy from George Polya: try to solve a simpler related problem. Try this problem: $[a∧(a→b)]→b$. From solving this problem, can you then solve your original problem?

Comment: Which logical equivalences can you use?  Can you use any deductive rules of inference which aren't equivalences?

Comment: To be frank, I created this problem on my own initiative so solve.

Comment: For the sake of a challenge, I'd prefer to not use deductive inferences, but rather keep it to logical equivalences

Answer (score 0):

We need the basic tautology of $p\to q\equiv\lnot p\lor q$, which only really needs truth tables to prove it.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&\lnot p&p\to q&\lnot p\lor q\\
\hline
F&F&T&T&T\\
F&T&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F&F\\
T&T&F&T&T
\end{array}

$p\to q$ is always true except for when the premise $p$ is true and the implication $q$ is false, and this is exactly the same truth table as $\lnot p\lor q$.

Then we have $(a)\land (\lnot a\lor b)\land(\lnot b\lor c)$. All $3$ brackets need to be true for the LHS to be true, and for this to happen we therefore need $a\land\top=\top$, which in turn implies we need $b\land\top=\top$, and this in turn implies $c\land\top=\top$. With $c\land\top=\top$ we are done, in that if the LHS is false, the implication is true.

Another way of looking at it is that $a\land (\lnot a\lor b)\land(\lnot b\lor c)\equiv a\land b\land c\equiv c$.